# How to make two ListViews scrolling up and down as one/together?

Tags: android, listview

I'm a student that just get into app development using android studio "plz keep this in mind when answering my q.".

I have an assignment that requires me to use SQLite to stores and retrieves data entered by the user and then displaying it in a ListView.
The output should be as two columns one holds a pc name, the other one holds the employee's name working on that pc.

I did all that, storing and retrieving works fine, however I did use two ListViews (which appeared to be a bad choice!) to display the data (pc & employee name), so the two lists are now scrolling up/down independent from one another. Screenshot to illustrate the problem:

[The two ListViews scrolling issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUdx5.png)

I googled for a solution, one is to design a custom layout, while another suggest using lines of code to do so {I tried the custom layout but it didn't work!}. I hope someone can help me pass this assignment:(

**Thanx^^
Nora.**

Comment: I believe you could simply use a gridview, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this has been posted before, anyway the answer seems to be addressed in this link
https://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/how-to-make-simultaneous-scrollable-views-in-android/